# Comparing 3 entered integers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do the following:

> Write a program that reads three numbers and prints “all the same”
>   if they are all the same, “all different” if they are all different,
>   and “neither” otherwise.
>
> Your program should request 3 integers via 3 input statements. Use a
>   combination of if, elif, and else to implement the algorithm that is
>   needed for this problem.

However, whenever I input all the same integers I get both 'all the same' and 'neither'. How do I make it so that my "neither" section is correct?

```
x=input('enter an integer:') 
y=input('enter an integer:') 
z=input('enter an integer:') 
if x==y and y==z: print('all the same') 
if not x==y and not y==z: print('all different') 
if x==y or y==z or z==x: print('neither')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: PS: Take a look at [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input) (or `raw_input()` in Python 2.x). The rest should be pretty trivial.

Comment: `x=input('enter an integer:')`
`y=input('enter an integer:')`
`z=input('enter an integer:')`

`if x==y and y==z:
    print('all the same')
if not x==y and not y==z:
    print('all different')
if x==y or y==z or z==x:
    print('neither')`

whenever i input all the same integers i get a all same and neither. how do i make it so that my "neither" section is correct?

Comment: Please edit that code into your question - the comments break code formatting.

Comment: -`x=input('enter an integer:')`
-`y=input('enter an integer:')`
-`=input('enter an integer:')`
-`if x==y and y==z: print('all the same')`
-`if not x==y and not y==z: print('all different')` 
-`if x==y or y==z or z==x: print('neither')`

Comment: To clarify, I mean use the edit button below the `python-3.x` tag above. That will ensure the indentation isn't lost.

Comment: So what you need to do is spelled out in your problem statement: use `if`, `elif`, and `else` for your three cases ([an example from the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)). The way your code is written now it evaluates all three if statements even if one of them has already evaluated to true, and when all integers are the same both the first and last conditionals are both true.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you use `if` for each case. This means all the cases are evaluated no matter what, and that multiple cases can be true.

For example, if all three variables are 1, the cases evaluate like this:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 1
>>> z = 1
>>> if x == y and y == z: print("all the same")

all the same
>>> if not x == y and not y == z: print("all different")

>>> if x == y or y == z or z == x: print('neither')

neither
>>>
```

You want to use `elif` (else if) and `else` ([see the flow control documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)) so your conditions become mutually exclusive:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 1
>>> z = 1
>>> if x == y and y == z: print("all the same")
elif not x == y and not y == z: print("all different")
else: print("neither")

all the same
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be: 
1) Use input
2) Use if, elif and else clauses

Something like this?

```
x = input("Enter the 1st integer")
y = input("Enter the 2nd integer")
z = input("Enter the 3rd integer")

if x == y and y == z:
    print("All the numbers are the same")

elif x!= y and y != z: # or use elif not and replace all != with ==
    print("None of the numbers are the same")

else:
    print("Neither")
```